# Masonry + infinite scroll - callback isn't working on WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

After many hours of research, I still can't integrate [the infinite Wordpress scroll plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) and [the masonry script](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

I downloaded and added the infinite scroll 2.6.2 plug-in to my Wordpress theme with the following callback:

```
// hide new items while they are loading
var $newElems = jQuery(newElements).css({ opacity: 0 });
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
// show elems now they're ready
$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
    $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
```

Also, the "Masonry/isotope" behaviour has been selected.

New posts are loaded, however, they are overloaded previous one and the masonry position isn't applied to new posts.

**HEADER**

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- Add the Jquery library -->
    <script src="http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var $container = $('#content'); // #content is my all .post container
            $container.masonry({
              columnWidth: 200,
              itemSelector: '.post'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**FOOTER**

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var infinite_scroll = "{\"loading\":{\"msgText\":\"\",\"finishedMsg\":\"\",\"img\":\"http:\\\/\\\/localhost\\\/dele\\\/wp-content\\\/plugins\\\/infinite-scroll\\\/img\\\/ajax-loader.gif\"},\"nextSelector\":\".infinite_nav a:first\",\"navSelector\":\".infinite_nav\",\"itemSelector\":\".post\",\"contentSelector\":\".masonry-area\",\"debug\":false,\"behavior\":\"masonry\",\"callback\":\"\\\/\\\/ hide new items while they are loading\\r\\nvar $newElems = jQuery(newElements).css({ opacity: 0 });\\r\\n\\\/\\\/ ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout\\r\\n$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){\\r\\n\\\/\\\/ show elems now they're ready\\r\\n$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });\\r\\n$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );\\r\\n});\"}";
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/dele/wp-content/plugins/infinite-scroll/js/front-end/jquery.infinitescroll.js?ver=2.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/dele/wp-content/plugins/infinite-scroll/behaviors/masonry-isotope.js?ver=2.6.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Because the `wp_localize_script` method makes everything a string
infinite_scroll = jQuery.parseJSON(infinite_scroll);

jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll, function(newElements, data, url) { eval(infinite_scroll.callback); });
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

            request = true;

            b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
            b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
        }());
    </script>
```

Any help will be really appriciated, thanks

Note: On the masonry-isotope.js file, I'm getting the following error on the .masonry calls :
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { console.log(jQuery.infinitescroll.prototype); // (1)
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.infinitescroll.prototype,{
        _callback_masonry: function infscr_callback_masonry (newElements) {
            console.log(jQuery(this)); // (2)
            jQuery(this).masonry('appended',jQuery(newElements)); 
        }
    }); })
```

**RESULTS**

**1**

```
Object {_binding: function, _create: function, _prefill: function, _debug: function, _determinepath: function…}
_binding: function g(F){var D=this,E=D.options;E.v="2.0b2.120520";if(!!E.behavior&&this["_binding_"+E.behavior]!==k){this["_binding_"+E.behavior].call(this);return}if(F!=="bind"&&F!=="unbind"){this._debug("Binding value "+F+" not valid");return false}if(F==="unbind"){(this.options.binder).unbind("smartscroll.infscr."+D.options.infid)}else{(this.options.binder)[F]("smartscroll.infscr."+D.options.infid,function(){D.scroll()})}this._debug("Binding",F)}
_callback_masonry: function infscr_callback_masonry(newElements) {
_create: function t(F,J){var G=i.extend(true,{},i.infinitescroll.defaults,F);this.options=G;var I=i(o);var D=this;if(!D._validate(F)){return false}var H=i(G.nextSelector).attr("href");if(!H){this._debug("Navigation selector not found");return false}G.path=G.path||this._determinepath(H);G.contentSelector=G.contentSelector||this.element;G.loading.selector=G.loading.selector||G.contentSelector;G.loading.msg=G.loading.msg||i('<div id="infscr-loading"><img alt="Loading..." src="'+G.loading.img+'" /><div>'+G.loading.msgText+"</div></div>");(new Image()).src=G.loading.img;if(G.pixelsFromNavToBottom===k){G.pixelsFromNavToBottom=i(document).height()-i(G.navSelector).offset().top}var E=this;G.loading.start=G.loading.start||function(){i(G.navSelector).hide();G.loading.msg.appendTo(G.loading.selector).show(G.loading.speed,i.proxy(function(){this.beginAjax(G)},E))};G.loading.finished=G.loading.finished||function(){G.loading.msg.fadeOut(G.loading.speed)};G.callback=function(K,M,L){if(!!G.behavior&&K["_callback_"+G.behavior]!==k){K["_callback_"+G.behavior].call(i(G.contentSelector)[0],M,L)}if(J){J.call(i(G.contentSelector)[0],M,G,L)}if(G.prefill){I.bind("resize.infinite-scroll",K._prefill)}};if(F.debug){if(Function.prototype.bind&&(typeof console==="object"||typeof console==="function")&&typeof console.log==="object"){["log","info","warn","error","assert","dir","clear","profile","profileEnd"].forEach(function(K){console[K]=this.call(console[K],console)},Function.prototype.bind)}}this._setup();if(G.prefill){this._prefill()}return true}
_debug: function q(){if(true!==this.options.debug){return}if(typeof console!=="undefined"&&typeof console.log==="function"){if((Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)).length===1&&typeof Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)[0]==="string"){console.log((Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)).toString())}else{console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))}}else{if(!Function.prototype.bind&&typeof console!=="undefined"&&typeof console.log==="object"){Function.prototype.call.call(console.log,console,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))}}}
_determinepath: function A(E){var D=this.options;if(!!D.behavior&&this["_determinepath_"+D.behavior]!==k){return this["_determinepath_"+D.behavior].call(this,E)}if(!!D.pathParse){this._debug("pathParse manual");return D.pathParse(E,this.options.state.currPage+1)}else{if(E.match(/^(.*?)\b2\b(.*?$)/)){E=E.match(/^(.*?)\b2\b(.*?$)/).slice(1)}else{if(E.match(/^(.*?)2(.*?$)/)){if(E.match(/^(.*?page=)2(\/.*|$)/)){E=E.match(/^(.*?page=)2(\/.*|$)/).slice(1);return E}E=E.match(/^(.*?)2(.*?$)/).slice(1)}else{if(E.match(/^(.*?page=)1(\/.*|$)/)){E=E.match(/^(.*?page=)1(\/.*|$)/).slice(1);return E}else{this._debug("Sorry, we couldn't parse your Next (Previous Posts) URL. Verify your the css selector points to the correct A tag. If you still get this error: yell, scream, and kindly ask for help at infinite-scroll.com.");D.state.isInvalidPage=true}}}}this._debug("determinePath",E);return E}
_error: function v(E){var D=this.options;if(!!D.behavior&&this["_error_"+D.behavior]!==k){this["_error_"+D.behavior].call(this,E);return}if(E!=="destroy"&&E!=="end"){E="unknown"}this._debug("Error",E);if(E==="end"){this._showdonemsg()}D.state.isDone=true;D.state.currPage=1;D.state.isPaused=false;this._binding("unbind")}
_loadcallback: function c(H,G,E){var D=this.options,J=this.options.callback,L=(D.state.isDone)?"done":(!D.appendCallback)?"no-append":"append",K;if(!!D.behavior&&this["_loadcallback_"+D.behavior]!==k){this["_loadcallback_"+D.behavior].call(this,H,G);return}switch(L){case"done":this._showdonemsg();return false;case"no-append":if(D.dataType==="html"){G="<div>"+G+"</div>";G=i(G).find(D.itemSelector)}break;case"append":var F=H.children();if(F.length===0){return this._error("end")}K=document.createDocumentFragment();while(H[0].firstChild){K.appendChild(H[0].firstChild)}this._debug("contentSelector",i(D.contentSelector)[0]);i(D.contentSelector)[0].appendChild(K);G=F.get();break}D.loading.finished.call(i(D.contentSelector)[0],D);if(D.animate){var I=i(o).scrollTop()+i("#infscr-loading").height()+D.extraScrollPx+"px";i("html,body").animate({scrollTop:I},800,function(){D.state.isDuringAjax=false})}if(!D.animate){D.state.isDuringAjax=false}J(this,G,E);if(D.prefill){this._prefill()}}
_nearbottom: function u(){var E=this.options,D=0+i(document).height()-(E.binder.scrollTop())-i(o).height();if(!!E.behavior&&this["_nearbottom_"+E.behavior]!==k){return this["_nearbottom_"+E.behavior].call(this)}this._debug("math:",D,E.pixelsFromNavToBottom);return(D-E.bufferPx<E.pixelsFromNavToBottom)}
_pausing: function l(E){var D=this.options;if(!!D.behavior&&this["_pausing_"+D.behavior]!==k){this["_pausing_"+D.behavior].call(this,E);return}if(E!=="pause"&&E!=="resume"&&E!==null){this._debug("Invalid argument. Toggling pause value instead")}E=(E&&(E==="pause"||E==="resume"))?E:"toggle";switch(E){case"pause":D.state.isPaused=true;break;case"resume":D.state.isPaused=false;break;case"toggle":D.state.isPaused=!D.state.isPaused;break}this._debug("Paused",D.state.isPaused);return false}
_prefill: function n(){var D=this;var G=i(document);var F=i(o);function E(){return(G.height()<=F.height())}this._prefill=function(){if(E()){D.scroll()}F.bind("resize.infinite-scroll",function(){if(E()){F.unbind("resize.infinite-scroll");D.scroll()}})};this._prefill()}
_setup: function r(){var D=this.options;if(!!D.behavior&&this["_setup_"+D.behavior]!==k){this["_setup_"+D.behavior].call(this);return}this._binding("bind");return false}
_showdonemsg: function a(){var D=this.options;if(!!D.behavior&&this["_showdonemsg_"+D.behavior]!==k){this["_showdonemsg_"+D.behavior].call(this);return}D.loading.msg.find("img").hide().parent().find("div").html(D.loading.finishedMsg).animate({opacity:1},2000,function(){i(this).parent().fadeOut(D.loading.speed)});D.errorCallback.call(i(D.contentSelector)[0],"done")}
_validate: function w(E){for(var D in E){if(D.indexOf&&D.indexOf("Selector")>-1&&i(E[D]).length===0){this._debug("Your "+D+" found no elements.");return false}}return true}
beginAjax: function B(G){var E=this,I=G.path,F,D,K,J;G.state.currPage++;if(G.maxPage!=k&&G.state.currPage>G.maxPage){this.destroy();return}F=i(G.contentSelector).is("table")?i("<tbody/>"):i("<div/>");D=(typeof I==="function")?I(G.state.currPage):I.join(G.state.currPage);E._debug("heading into ajax",D);K=(G.dataType==="html"||G.dataType==="json")?G.dataType:"html+callback";if(G.appendCallback&&G.dataType==="html"){K+="+callback"}switch(K){case"html+callback":E._debug("Using HTML via .load() method");F.load(D+" "+G.itemSelector,k,function H(L){E._loadcallback(F,L,D)});break;case"html":E._debug("Using "+(K.toUpperCase())+" via $.ajax() method");i.ajax({url:D,dataType:G.dataType,complete:function H(L,M){J=(typeof(L.isResolved)!=="undefined")?(L.isResolved()):(M==="success"||M==="notmodified");if(J){E._loadcallback(F,L.responseText,D)}else{E._error("end")}}});break;case"json":E._debug("Using "+(K.toUpperCase())+" via $.ajax() method");i.ajax({dataType:"json",type:"GET",url:D,success:function(N,O,M){J=(typeof(M.isResolved)!=="undefined")?(M.isResolved()):(O==="success"||O==="notmodified");if(G.appendCallback){if(G.template!==k){var L=G.template(N);F.append(L);if(J){E._loadcallback(F,L)}else{E._error("end")}}else{E._debug("template must be defined.");E._error("end")}}else{if(J){E._loadcallback(F,N,D)}else{E._error("end")}}},error:function(){E._debug("JSON ajax request failed.");E._error("end")}});break}}
bind: function p(){this._binding("bind")}
destroy: function C(){this.options.state.isDestroyed=true;this.options.loading.finished();return this._error("destroy")}
pause: function e(){this._pausing("pause")}
resume: function h(){this._pausing("resume")}
retrieve: function b(F){F=F||null;var D=this,E=D.options;if(!!E.behavior&&this["retrieve_"+E.behavior]!==k){this["retrieve_"+E.behavior].call(this,F);return}if(E.state.isDestroyed){this._debug("Instance is destroyed");return false}E.state.isDuringAjax=true;E.loading.start.call(i(E.contentSelector)[0],E)}
scroll: function f(){var D=this.options,E=D.state;if(!!D.behavior&&this["scroll_"+D.behavior]!==k){this["scroll_"+D.behavior].call(this);return}if(E.isDuringAjax||E.isInvalidPage||E.isDone||E.isDestroyed||E.isPaused){return}if(!this._nearbottom()){return}this.retrieve()}
toggle: function y(){this._pausing()}
unbind: function m(){this._binding("unbind")}
update: function j(D){if(i.isPlainObject(D)){this.options=i.extend(true,this.options,D)}}
__proto__: Object
```

**2**

```
[div#post-area.masonry-area.isotope, context: div#post-area.masonry-area.isotope, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
0: div#post-area.masonry-area.isotope
context: div#post-area.masonry-area.isotope
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
_scrollable: function (){return this.map(function(){var a=this,isWin=!a.nodeName||$.inArray(a.nodeName.toLowerCase(),['iframe','#document','html','body'])!=-1;if(!isWin)return a;var b=(a.contentWindow||a).document||a.ownerDocument||a;return/webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)||b.compatMode=='BackCompat'?b.body:b.documentElement})}
add: function (a,b){return this.pushStack(n.unique(n.merge(this.get(),n(a,b))))}
addBack: function (a){return this.add(null==a?this.prevObject:this.prevObject.filter(a))}
addClass: function (a){var b,c,d,e,f,g,h=0,i=this.length,j="string"==typeof a&&a;if(n.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){n(this).addClass(a.call(this,b,this.className))});if(j)for(b=(a||"").match(F)||[];i>h;h++)if(c=this[h],d=1===c.nodeType&&(c.className?(" "+c.className+" ").replace(vc," "):" ")){f=0;while(e=b[f++])d.indexOf(" "+e+" ")<0&&(d+=e+" ");g=n.trim(d),c.className!==g&&(c.className=g)}return this}
after: function (){return this.domManip(arguments,function(a){this.parentNode&&this.parentNode.insertBefore(a,this.nextSibling)})}
ajaxComplete: function (a){return this.on(b,a)}
ajaxError: function (a){return this.on(b,a)}
ajaxSend: function (a){return this.on(b,a)}
ajaxStart: function (a){return this.on(b,a)}
ajaxStop: function (a){return this.on(b,a)}
ajaxSuccess: function (a){return this.on(b,a)}
andSelf: function (){return r("jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack()"),w.apply(this,arguments)}
animate: function (a,b,c,d){var e=n.isEmptyObject(a),f=n.speed(b,c,d),g=function(){var b=lc(this,n.extend({},a),f);(e||n._data(this,"finish"))&&b.stop(!0)};return g.finish=g,e||f.queue===!1?this.each(g):this.queue(f.queue,g)}
append: function (){return this.domManip(arguments,function(a){if(1===this.nodeType||11===this.nodeType||9===this.nodeType){var b=xb(this,a);b.appendChild(a)}})}
appendTo: function (a){for(var c,d=0,e=[],g=n(a),h=g.length-1;h>=d;d++)c=d===h?this:this.clone(!0),n(g[d])[b](c),f.apply(e,c.get());return this.pushStack(e)}
attr: function (a,b){return W(this,n.attr,a,b,arguments.length>1)}
before: function (){return this.domManip(arguments,function(a){this.parentNode&&this.parentNode.insertBefore(a,this)})}
bind: function (a,b,c){return this.on(a,null,b,c)}
blur: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
change: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
children: function (c,d){var e=n.map(this,b,c);return"Until"!==a.slice(-5)&&(d=c),d&&"string"==typeof d&&(e=n.filter(d,e)),this.length>1&&(D[a]||(e=n.unique(e)),C.test(a)&&(e=e.reverse())),this.pushStack(e)}
clearQueue: function (a){return this.queue(a||"fx",[])}
click: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
clone: function (a,b){return a=null==a?!1:a,b=null==b?a:b,this.map(function(){return n.clone(this,a,b)})}
closest: function (a,b){for(var c,d=0,e=this.length,f=[],g=u.test(a)||"string"!=typeof a?n(a,b||this.context):0;e>d;d++)for(c=this[d];c&&c!==b;c=c.parentNode)if(c.nodeType<11&&(g?g.index(c)>-1:1===c.nodeType&&n.find.matchesSelector(c,a))){f.push(c);break}return this.pushStack(f.length>1?n.unique(f):f)}
constructor: function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
contents: function (c,d){var e=n.map(this,b,c);return"Until"!==a.slice(-5)&&(d=c),d&&"string"==typeof d&&(e=n.filter(d,e)),this.length>1&&(D[a]||(e=n.unique(e)),C.test(a)&&(e=e.reverse())),this.pushStack(e)}
contextmenu: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
css: function (a,b){return W(this,function(a,b,c){var d,e,f={},g=0;if(n.isArray(b)){for(d=Jb(a),e=b.length;e>g;g++)f[b[g]]=n.css(a,b[g],!1,d);return f}return void 0!==c?n.style(a,b,c):n.css(a,b)
data: function (t){var a,i,o=this[0];return!o||"events"!==t||1!==arguments.length||(a=e.data(o,t),i=e._data(o,t),a!==n&&a!==i||i===n)?b.apply(this,arguments):(r("Use of jQuery.fn.data('events') is deprecated"),i)}
dblclick: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
delay: function (a,b){return a=n.fx?n.fx.speeds[a]||a:a,b=b||"fx",this.queue(b,function(b,c){var d=setTimeout(b,a);c.stop=function(){clearTimeout(d)}})}
delegate: function (a,b,c,d){return this.on(b,a,c,d)}
dequeue: function (a){return this.each(function(){n.dequeue(this,a)})}
detach: function (a){return this.remove(a,!0)}
die: function (t,n){return r("jQuery.fn.die() is deprecated"),M?M.apply(this,arguments):(e(this.context).off(t,this.selector||"**",n),this)}
domManip: function (a,b){a=e.apply([],a);var c,d,f,g,h,i,j=0,k=this.length,m=this,o=k-1,p=a[0],q=n.isFunction(p);if(q||k>1&&"string"==typeof p&&!l.checkClone&&ob.test(p))return this.each(function(c){var d=m.eq(c);q&&(a[0]=p.call(this,c,d.html())),d.domManip(a,b)});if(k&&(i=n.buildFragment(a,this[0].ownerDocument,!1,this),c=i.firstChild,1===i.childNodes.length&&(i=c),c)){for(g=n.map(vb(i,"script"),yb),f=g.length;k>j;j++)d=i,j!==o&&(d=n.clone(d,!0,!0),f&&n.merge(g,vb(d,"script"))),b.call(this[j],d,j);if(f)for(h=g[g.length-1].ownerDocument,n.map(g,zb),j=0;f>j;j++)d=g[j],pb.test(d.type||"")&&!n._data(d,"globalEval")&&n.contains(h,d)&&(d.src?n._evalUrl&&n._evalUrl(d.src):n.globalEval((d.text||d.textContent||d.innerHTML||"").replace(rb,"")));i=c=null}return this}
each: function (a,b){return n.each(this,a,b)}
easyPieChart: function (options) {
empty: function (){for(var a,b=0;null!=(a=this[b]);b++){1===a.nodeType&&n.cleanData(vb(a,!1));while(a.firstChild)a.removeChild(a.firstChild);a.options&&n.nodeName(a,"select")&&(a.options.length=0)}return this}
end: function (){return this.prevObject||this.constructor(null)}
eq: function (a){var b=this.length,c=+a+(0>a?b:0);return this.pushStack(c>=0&&b>c?[this[c]]:[])}
error: function (){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);return r("jQuery.fn.error() is deprecated"),e.splice(0,0,"error"),arguments.length?this.bind.apply(this,e):(this.triggerHandler.apply(this,e),this)}
extend: function (){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g=arguments[0]||{},h=1,i=arguments.length,j=!1;for("boolean"==typeof g&&(j=g,g=arguments[h]||{},h++),"object"==typeof g||n.isFunction(g)||(g={}),h===i&&(g=this,h--);i>h;h++)if(null!=(e=arguments[h]))for(d in e)a=g[d],c=e[d],g!==c&&(j&&c&&(n.isPlainObject(c)||(b=n.isArray(c)))?(b?(b=!1,f=a&&n.isArray(a)?a:[]):f=a&&n.isPlainObject(a)?a:{},g[d]=n.extend(j,f,c)):void 0!==c&&(g[d]=c));return g}
fadeIn: function (a,c,d){return this.animate(b,a,c,d)}
fadeOut: function (a,c,d){return this.animate(b,a,c,d)}
fadeTo: function (a,b,c,d){return this.filter(V).css("opacity",0).show().end().animate({opacity:b},a,c,d)}
fadeToggle: function (a,c,d){return this.animate(b,a,c,d)}
fancybox: function (a){var d,e=f(this),c=this.selector||"",k=function(g){var h=f(this).blur(),j=d,k,l;!g.ctrlKey&&(!g.altKey&&!g.shiftKey&&!g.metaKey)&&!h.is(".fancybox-wrap")&&(k=a.groupAttr||"data-fancybox-group",l=h.attr(k),l||(k="rel",l=h.get(0)[k]),l&&(""!==l&&"nofollow"!==l)&&(h=c.length?f(c):e,h=h.filter("["+k+'="'+l+
filter: function (a){return this.pushStack(x(this,a||[],!1))}
find: function (a){var b,c=[],d=this,e=d.length;if("string"!=typeof a)return this.pushStack(n(a).filter(function(){for(b=0;e>b;b++)if(n.contains(d[b],this))return!0}));for(b=0;e>b;b++)n.find(a,d[b],c);return c=this.pushStack(e>1?n.unique(c):c),c.selector=this.selector?this.selector+" "+a:a,c}
finish: function (a){return a!==!1&&(a=a||"fx"),this.each(function(){var b,c=n._data(this),d=c[a+"queue"],e=c[a+"queueHooks"],f=n.timers,g=d?d.length:0;for(c.finish=!0,n.queue(this,a,[]),e&&e.stop&&e.stop.call(this,!0),b=f.length;b--;)f[b].elem===this&&f[b].queue===a&&(f[b].anim.stop(!0),f.splice(b,1));for(b=0;g>b;b++)d[b]&&d[b].finish&&d[b].finish.call(this);delete c.finish})}
first: function (){return this.eq(0)}
fitVids: function ( options ) {
flexslider: function (i){void 0===i&&(i={});if("object"===typeof i)return this.each(function(){var a=d(this),c=a.find(i.selector?i.selector:".slides > li");1===c.length?(c.fadeIn(400),i.start&&i.start(a)):void 0===a.data("flexslider")&&new d.flexslider(this,i)});var k=d(this).data("flexslider");
focus: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
focusin: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
focusout: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
get: function (a){return null!=a?0>a?this[a+this.length]:this[a]:d.call(this)}
has: function (a){var b,c=n(a,this),d=c.length;return this.filter(function(){for(b=0;d>b;b++)if(n.contains(this,c[b]))return!0})}
hasClass: function (a){for(var b=" "+a+" ",c=0,d=this.length;d>c;c++)if(1===this[c].nodeType&&(" "+this[c].className+" ").replace(vc," ").indexOf(b)>=0)return!0;return!1}
height: function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return W(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)}
hide: function (a,d,e){return null==a||"boolean"==typeof a?c.apply(this,arguments):this.animate(hc(b,!0),a,d,e)}
hover: function (a,b){return this.mouseenter(a).mouseleave(b||a)}
hoverIntent: function (b,c,d){var e={interval:100,sensitivity:7,timeout:0};e="object"==typeof b?a.extend(e,b):a.isFunction(c)?a.extend(e,{over:b,out:c,selector:d}):a.extend(e,{over:b,out:b,selector:c});var f,g,h,i,j=function(a){f=a.pageX,g=a.pageY},k=function(b,c){return c.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(c.hoverIntent_t),Math.abs(h-f)+Math.abs(i-g)<e.sensitivity?(a(c).off("mousemove.hoverIntent",j),c.hoverIntent_s=1,e.over.apply(c,[b])):(h=f,i=g,c.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){k(b,c)},e.interval),void 0)},l=function(a,b){return b.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(b.hoverIntent_t),b.hoverIntent_s=0,e.out.apply(b,[a])},m=function(b){var c=jQuery.extend({},b),d=this;d.hoverIntent_t&&(d.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(d.hoverIntent_t)),"mouseenter"==b.type?(h=c.pageX,i=c.pageY,a(d).on("mousemove.hoverIntent",j),1!=d.hoverIntent_s&&(d.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){k(c,d)},e.interval))):(a(d).off("mousemove.hoverIntent",j),1==d.hoverIntent_s&&(d.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){l(c,d)},e.timeout)))};return this.on({"mouseenter.hoverIntent":m,"mouseleave.hoverIntent":m},e.selector)}
html: function (a){return W(this,function(a){var b=this[0]||{},c=0,d=this.length;if(void 0===a)return 1===b.nodeType?b.innerHTML.replace(gb,""):void 0;if(!("string"!=typeof a||nb.test(a)||!l.htmlSerialize&&hb.test(a)||!l.leadingWhitespace&&ib.test(a)||sb[(kb.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()])){a=a.replace(jb,"<$1></$2>");try{for(;d>c;c++)b=this[c]||{},1===b.nodeType&&(n.cleanData(vb(b,!1)),b.innerHTML=a);b=0}catch(e){}}b&&this.empty().append(a)},null,a,arguments.length)}
imagesLoaded: function (a){function h(){a.call(c,d)}function i(a){var c=a.target;c.src!==f&&b.inArray(c,g)===-1&&(g.push(c),--e<=0&&(setTimeout(h),d.unbind(".imagesLoaded",i)))}var c=this,d=c.find("img").add(c.filter("img")),e=d.length,f="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==",g=[];return e||h(),d.bind("load.imagesLoaded error.imagesLoaded",i).each(function(){var a=this.src;this.src=f,this.src=a}),c}
index: function (a){return a?"string"==typeof a?n.inArray(this[0],n(a)):n.inArray(a.jquery?a[0]:a,this):this[0]&&this[0].parentNode?this.first().prevAll().length:-1}
infinitescroll: function d(F,G){var E=typeof F;switch(E){case"string":var D=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);this.each(function(){var H=i.data(this,"infinitescroll");if(!H){return false}if(!i.isFunction(H[F])||F.charAt(0)==="_"){return false}H[F].apply(H,D)});break;case"object":this.each(function(){var H=i.data(this,"infinitescroll");if(H){H.update(F)}else{H=new i.infinitescroll(F,G,this);if(!H.failed){i.data(this,"infinitescroll",H)}}});break}return this}


BLA BLA BLA


trigger: function (a,b){return this.each(function(){n.event.trigger(a,b,this)})}
triggerHandler: function (a,b){var c=this[0];return c?n.event.trigger(a,b,c,!0):void 0}
unbind: function (a,b){return this.off(a,null,b)}
undelegate: function (a,b,c){return 1===arguments.length?this.off(a,"**"):this.off(b,a||"**",c)}
unload: function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
unwrap: function (){return this.parent().each(function(){n.nodeName(this,"body")||n(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes)}).end()}
val: function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return d=n.isFunction(a),this.each(function(c){var e;1===this.nodeType&&(e=d?a.call(this,c,n(this).val()):a,null==e?e="":"number"==typeof e?e+="":n.isArray(e)&&(e=n.map(e,function(a){return null==a?"":a+""})),b=n.valHooks[this.type]||n.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"set"in b&&void 0!==b.set(this,e,"value")||(this.value=e))});if(e)return b=n.valHooks[e.type]||n.valHooks[e.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"get"in b&&void 0!==(c=b.get(e,"value"))?c:(c=e.value,"string"==typeof c?c.replace(mc,""):null==c?"":c)}}
width: function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return W(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)}
wrap: function (a){var b=n.isFunction(a);return this.each(function(c){n(this).wrapAll(b?a.call(this,c):a)})}
wrapAll: function (a){if(n.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){n(this).wrapAll(a.call(this,b))});if(this[0]){var b=n(a,this[0].ownerDocument).eq(0).clone(!0);this[0].parentNode&&b.insertBefore(this[0]),b.map(function(){var a=this;while(a.firstChild&&1===a.firstChild.nodeType)a=a.firstChild;return a}).append(this)}return this}
wrapInner: function (a){return this.each(n.isFunction(a)?function(b){n(this).wrapInner(a.call(this,b))}:function(){var b=n(this),c=b.contents();c.length?c.wrapAll(a):b.append(a)})}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Are you sure your *** line is the good one ? In your console, what's the result of `jQuery.infinitescroll.prototype` ?

Comment: Let me create a staging server with my project, so you will have a direct access to it

Comment: I'm just curious but why at first you call masonry on div with id #content and second on div#post-area (according console log information)? I tried to recreate the situation but I can't because of it's unclear where to put the first code block from your question

Answer (score 1):

Try this, replace your masonry-isotope.js content with :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.infinitescroll.prototype,{
        _callback_masonry: function infscr_callback_masonry (newElements) {
            jQuery(this).masonry('appended',jQuery(newElements)); 
        }
    });
})
```

If this works, this is due to the $ shortcut, not supported with your theme (your theme called jQuery.noConflict, disabling $ shortcut in case to avoid conflicts with other libraries).

Comment: Nice though, however, I still have the same issue. Let me update my question with more code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/ is more advance and excellent as compare to infinite scroll..